# Explode with string, search in array and return it's value

Tags: php, explode

I'm trying to make Country slug converter to short name. So I created this function:

```
<?php 
function convertCountry( $countrySlug ) {
    $countries = "Andorra: AR|United-Arab-Emirates: UAE|Afghanistan: AFG|Antigua-And-Barbuda: AAB|Anguilla: ANG|Albania: ALB|Armenia: ARM";

    $countryArray = explode('|', $countries);

    return array_search($countrySlug, $countryArray);
}

echo convertCountry('United-Arab-Emirates');
?>
```

It must be print **UAE** but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_search` will find the equal text. In your case, I think we should use `strpos`.

```
function strpos_array($countryArray, $countrySlug) {
    if (is_array($countryArray)) {
        foreach ($countryArray as $country) {
            if (($pos= strpos($country, $countrySlug)) !== false) {
                return str_replace($countrySlug.': ', '', $country);
            };
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function convertCountry($countrySlug) {
    $countries = "Andorra: AR|United-Arab-Emirates: UAE|Afghanistan: AFG|Antigua-And-Barbuda: AAB|Anguilla: ANG|Albania: ALB|Armenia: ARM";

    $countryArray = explode('|', $countries);

    return strpos_array($countryArray, $countrySlug);
}
echo convertCountry('United-Arab-Emirates');
//This will print UAE
```